# Is it possible to store JSON object's key-value pair as string array?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to loop through these JSON key-value pairs:

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "component_name": "ORDERPLACEMENT",
    "source_system": "X1",
    "msg_direction": "O",
    "correlation_id": "ORD001",
    "SourceType": "StoreOrder",
    "startdate": "2021-04-30",
    "enddate": "2021-05-30"    
}
```

and store it as an array, e.g:

```
string[] keys = {id, component_name, source_system, msg_direction, correlation_id, SourceType, startdate, enddate};
string[] val = {"001", "ORDERPLACEMENT", "X1", "O", "ORD001", "StoreOrder", "2021-04-30", "2021-05-30"};
```

Reason:
I have a REST API CreateDocumentQuery to read from Azure cosmos DB to which I need to send these array values as where clause components.
`"Select * from c where" + " c.id = "001" and c.component_name= "ORDERPLACEMENT".. etc."`
The parameters are dynamic and not all key-value pairs will be sent every time, so I need to dynamically pull it from the JSON and pass the same.
I'm a beginner coder so appreciate all the help immensely!

Edit: My solution #1 works but not efficient and I'm not a fan of using queries like 1=1 just to get to the result. Please review and provide alternatives! Thanks.

```
 public static string DictDeserial(string jObj)
        {
            var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jObj);
            StringBuilder qr = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> d in values)
            {
               qr.Append(" and c." + d.Key + " = \"" + d.Value + "\"");
            }
            return qr.ToString();
        }
        public static string Getqrystring()
        {
            string json = @"{""id"": ""002"",""component_name"": ""ORDERPLACEMENT"",""correlation_id"": ""ORD001"", ""SourceType: ""StoreOrder""}";
            String qr = DictDeserial(json);
            return qr;
        }
public IQueryable<Item> Messagesearch() //Test
        {
            string qry = Getqrystring();
            return _documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Item>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId),
                "SELECT * from c WHERE 1=1" +qry , new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true });

        }
```

Comment: What programming language will you be using?

Comment: I'm using c# to develop REST API. 
I was able to find a solution to my problem but I'm sure there is an easier way to do this instead of my roundabout method.

Comment: Great! Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written so far and your concerns about that code.

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure I understand what your specific question is. Cosmos DB will let you store any string content you want within an individual property's value, and you may also have a variable number of properties within a given document, so you have a lot of flexibility for how you store and retrieve your data. However, as written, 1) it's not very clear what you're trying to fix, and 2) this seems like a broad, opinion-soliciting question (asking for general improvement ideas on something).

Comment: Apologies for the vague problem description!
I'm developing a code to accept inputs from a web form and pass the parameters as a JSON object to REST API GET. The parameters are compared against Azure Cosmos DB and the results are published. I'm able to solve this with the above piece of code but I was wondering if there is a more efficient method? My question now is - Can we pass JSON object as params to DocumentQuery to retrieve data from Azure Cosmos DB? Maybe I should move this to a new topic.